# Need help in a block pully question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

[image]

Consider the block-pulley system in the image with bodies $m_1,m_2$ and $m_3$ having masses $1$ kg, $2$ kg and $3$ kg respectively. Assume the strings and pulleys are massless.

**Will $m_2$ move downward or upward with respect to the ground?**

The solution given is that it goes upward. But if $m_2$ and $m_3$ are considered a system then they are heavier than $m_1$ and thus will give a greater acceleration to $m_1$ than what $m_3$ would give to $m_2$. With respect to the ground $m_2$ should move in downward direction.

What determines the direction of motion of $m_2$?

Comment: Hint: Tension adds linearly in massless pulleys.

Comment: I think you are correct. By my calculations $m_1$ accelerates upwards at $\frac {19} {29} g$; $m_2$ accelerates downwards at $\frac {17} {29} g$; and $m_3$ accelerates downwards at $\frac {21} {29} g$.